# Validate hex number with fixed length

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

I am trying to create field validation for hex number with 12 digits (MAC address). I came up with this *not-at-all-pretty* formula:

**EDIT**: Fixed some logical errors, so answers don't have to include that.

```
=AND(
LEN([MAC_x0020_adresa])=12,
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
OR(
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<58)=2),
((CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))>96)+(CODE(MID([MAC_x0020_adresa],13,1))<103)=2)
)
)
```

But SharePoint complains that the length of the formula exceeds 1024 characters. Can I shorten this formula, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you try using a regular expression rather than this long function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address has a possible expression you could try

Comment: Odd, I usually start from regex.. From searching, I can see that I can use javascript, but how do I actually _use_ it? Where should I input the javascript code?

Comment: Is this validation for a form? If so, you can use a validation rule through InfoPath with a custom pattern of `[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:][0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:][0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:][0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:][0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:][0-9A-Fa-f]{2}` - I've just tested this on my SP2010 and it works quite nicely... surprised myself! It seems SharePoint regular expression handling is pretty poor for complex expressions that could make this a breeze.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried using InfoPath, but I can't publish anything. It throws an error: `The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`